# Rails + Capybara: How do I loop through all links with certain text?

Tags: capybara

I have a bunch of anchor tags with text `Delete Image`. How do I loop through all of them and click them one by one? They all use AJAX. This doesn't work:

```
When(/^I delete all the section images$/) do
  page.all(:link, "Delete Image").each do |link|
    click_link(link)
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
  end
  sleep 1
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
When(/^I delete all the section images$/) do
  all(:link, "Delete Image").each do |link|
    link.click
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
  end
  sleep 1
end
```

the `link` parameter passed into the loop is an instance of a capybara class that can respond to `#click`. `click_link("text")` only works on matching the text.

Comment: Perhaps a little elaboration on the change and how/why it works?